# React js object for loop not return meta tags

Tags: reactjs, redux, lodash

Hear i call display page view function component load

```
render() {
    const { currentPageData } = this.props;
    return (
        <div>
            {this.displayPageView()}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Hear displaPageView function

```
displayPageView(){
    const obj = {
        centralead : {add: "1", edit: "1", index: "1", delete: "1"},
        contacts : {add: "1", edit: "1", index: "1", view: "1", archive: "1"},
        links : {add: "1", edit: "1", index: "1", view: "1", delete: "1"}
    };
    forEach(accessKey,(value,key) => {
        console.log("key >>",key);
        forEach(value,(value2,key2) => {
            console.log("value2 >>",value2);
            console.log("key2 >>",key2);
            return (<div><h1>{key}</h1><h1>{key2}</h1><h1>{value2}</h1></div>);
        });
    });
}
```

I got key and value in console.log but bot return view of that component.I used foreach from **'lodash'**.

Answer (score 0):

Lodash's [`forEach`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#forEach) doesn't return anything, use [`map`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#map) instead:

```js
const map = _.map;

class Demo extends React.Component {
  render() {
      return (
          <div>
              {this.displayPageView()}
          </div>
      )
  }

  displayPageView(){
      const obj = {
          centralead : {add: "1", edit: "1", index: "1", delete: "1"},
          contacts : {add: "1", edit: "1", index: "1", view: "1", archive: "1"},
          links : {add: "1", edit: "1", index: "1", view: "1", delete: "1"}
      };
      
      return map(obj, (value,key) => map(value,(value2,key2) => (
        <div><h1>{key}</h1><h1>{key2}</h1><h1>{value2}</h1></div>
      )));
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(
  <Demo />, 
  demo
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="demo"></div>
```